# Can age be determined by metals used on tricycle

Tags: vintage, fenders

[image: left side of frame under seat]I wasn't sure if I shou[image: right side of frame opposite the other number under seat]ld add to my last question or start another. Sorry if starting another is an issue. But as I'm sanding down the entire Miami Sun tricycle to get horrible paint job and rust off I come across all genders and chain guard are actually made from copper. With no serial number, I can't date it but would there maybe be a point in time these trikes were made out of that say due to wars/ metal shortage or whatnot to help determine how old it is[image: chain gaurd]

Comment: They may be copper plated steel. At one time copper was plated prior to chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really possible to date a frame based on metals used - steel bikes have been made for a hundred years, whereas aluminium have existed in some form since the 1930s, and carbon bikes first appeared in the 80s.

Other features and design elements are more likely to date a bike to a decade in the last 50 years, with older bikes being harder to date.

No bike would be made from copper - its not strong enough to form a frame, and has always been quite expensive. Also it gets flimsy when made into large thin sheets.   That chain cover might be made from brass or bronze  but those are also unusual choices.

Try a magnet on the metal and you'll probably find its steel with some kind of brownish hue.